# Como somar os elementos da mesma classe de um grupo de tabelas

Tags: jquery

Oi, me deram uma resposta correta em uma pergunta bem parecida, mas faltou esse detalhe que não consigo resolver...como somar os elementos da mesma classe de um grupo de tabelas...

Exemplo:

### **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/3/)**

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janmembros" maxlength="3" name="janmembros" value="1" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janvisitantes" maxlength="3" name="janvisitantes" value="3" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela3" class="jantotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janmembros" maxlength="3" name="janmembros" value="1" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janvisitantes" maxlength="3" name="janvisitantes" value="2" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela3" class="jantotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janmembros" maxlength="3" name="janmembros" value="1" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela">
            <input type="text" id="tabelainput" class="janvisitantes" maxlength="3" name="janvisitantes" value="5" disabled>
        </td>
        <td id="tabela3" class="jantotal">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tabela">
        </td>
        <td id="tabela">
        </td>
        <td id="tabela3" class="total">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
if ( $( ".janmembros" ).val() != '' && $( ".janvisitantes" ).val() != '' )
{
    $('table').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            janmembros = parseInt($this.find( ".janmembros" ).val()),
            janvisitantes = parseInt($this.find( ".janvisitantes" ).val());

        $this.find( ".jantotal" ).html( janmembros+janvisitantes );
        $( ".total" ).html($this.find( ".jantotal" ).html()); // essa linha deveria somar todos as classes .jantotal, mas só soma a última...
    });

}
```

### EDIT:

Depois da ajuda do @Sergio eu ainda fiquei sem conseguir resolver o problema, segue o JSFiddle com novas informações do problema: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/13/)**
São duas divs com as tabelas dentro e preciso da soma de cada uma das divs...eu preciso pular pra próxima soma da próxima div !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro, e como o @Zuul referiu tens de livrar-te dessas IDs duplicadas no caso de essas tabelas virem a estar na primeira página.

### Para escolher só uma tabela:

Tendo dito isso o que precisas é de selecionar a tabela que queres. Ou dando-lhe uma ID ou usando indice `.eq()`.

Asim, por exemplo para escolher a primeira podia usar-se estes seletores:

`$('table:first')` ou `$('table:eq(0)')` ou ainda `$('table').eq(0)`

No caso da segunda: `$('table:eq(1)')` ou ainda `$('table').eq(1)`

### Para escolher só uma classe:

```
$('.nomeDaClasse')
```

O problema no teu código é que não estás a somar. Estás a reescrever o valor a cada iteração de uma nova tabela.

Um exemplo simples seria:

```
$('.janmembros').each(function () {
    totalJanmembros += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
alert(totalJanmembros);
```

Nota que uso o `parseInt(valorString, base10)` para converter os valores em formato string para numéricos.

Um exemplo com o teu código, somando as classes `.janmembros`:

```
var somatorio = 0;
$('table').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        janmembros = parseInt($this.find(".janmembros").val(), 10),
        janvisitantes = parseInt($this.find(".janvisitantes").val(), 10);
    $this.find(".jantotal").html(janmembros + janvisitantes);
    somatorio += janmembros || 0;
});
$(".total").html(somatorio);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/6/

Comment: e para somar o valor de todos da mesma classe ?

Comment: @AlanPS, mas você quer somar uma a uma, certo?

Comment: não, quero o valor total de todos itens da mesma classe...a soma de todos!

Comment: @AlanPS, exato, uma a uma, classe a classe. É o exemplo que coloquei. Vou juntar essa ideia ao seu código e colocar aqui

Comment: @AlanPS: http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/6/

Comment: é isso mesmo, só tem um detalhe, preciso somar o campo "jantotal" e se eu trocar a classe no seu exemplo do jsfiddle não funciona...

Comment: @AlanPS ou usa o meu exemplo simples na resposta, depois do código que já tem, ou então pode usar assim: http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/7/

Comment: ah, valew @Sergio, consegui, so alterei a linha 7 do exemplo para: **somatorio += parseInt($this.find('.jantotal').html()) || 0;**  http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/9/

Comment: @AlanPS, essa versão que colocou funciona mas não é boa. Dê uma olhada ao meu ultimo comentário em cima. Você já tem esse valor, não precisa de ir fazer outro `.find()` que só atrasa tudo. E use sempre o parseInt com o segundo parâmetro, a não ser que queira converter numeros com base octal.

Comment: e nesse caso ? http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/10/

Comment: @AlanPS, assim está bem melhor!

Comment: mas como pegar o resultado da segunda div dai ?

Comment: @AlanPS explique melhor o que quer dizer com 2a div

Comment: nesse caso http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/13/, são duas divs com as tabelas dentro e preciso da soma de cada uma das divs...eu preciso pular pra próxima soma da próxima div

Answer (score 2):

Consegui da seguinte forma:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6g6Wd/18/)

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var somatorio = 0;
    $('table', this).each(function (i) {
        var $this = $(this),
            janmembros = parseInt($this.find('.janmembros').val() || '0', 10),
            janvisitantes = parseInt($this.find('.janvisitantes').val() || '0', 10);
        $this.find('.jantotal').html(janmembros + janvisitantes);
        somatorio += parseInt($this.find( ".jantotal" ).html() || '0', 10);
    });
    $('.total', this).html(somatorio);
});
```

Comment: AlanPS, exato! Ontem já era bem tarde aqui na Europa por isso só vi a sua pergunta agora. Fico contente de ter ajudado. Já agora, e só para alargar o  seu conhecimento, este selector `$('table', this)` é o memo que `$(this).find('table');`, e ambos fazem o que você precisava aqui.